# NSScrollView do not display the horizontal scroll bar if displayed from a plugin in a browser

Tags: macos, firefox, scrollview, scroller

I am developing a web application that uses a plugin to display some native Content. I create a NSView(say A) and return the CALayer of the NSView to the browser for hosting on the browser window. Inside this NSView I host a NSScrollView; The ScrollView contains the actual document that needs to be scrolled(the size of the document is big enough that both the horizontal and vertical scroll bars need to be displayed). I am setting the bounds of the Host NSView(A) as the frame size on the NSScrollView properly; Also I made sure on the ScrollView I am setting setHasHorizontalScroller and setHasVerticalScroller as YES.

Though the veritical scroll bar is displayed in the viewer, the horizontal scroll bar is not getting displayed. I want to know what the error I am making and why the horizontal scrollbar is not displayed. Any clues/suggestions on this is greatly appreciated.